# No data found error in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Please find below the stored procedure that I have written:

```
create or replace

procedure CursorProc_test_vp

(

  v_Cur IN OUT types.ref_cursor,

  count_var IN OUT number,

  var1 IN OUT varchar2,

  var2 IN OUT number,

  var3 IN  OUT number

)

as

begin

  select count(*) into count_var from vendor_backup;

  open v_Cur for 'select column1,column2 from BACKUP where column1 is not null and column2 is null';

    while count_var>0

    loop

      fetch v_Cur into var1,var2;

          SELECT ID into variable3 from BACKUP where column3 = var1;

          UPDATE BACKUP SET column2 = var3;

        count_var:=count_var-1;

      end loop;

  close v_cur;

end;
```

When I run the query with which I am opening the cursor I get 120 records.
But when I run this stored procedure it says "No data found".

It has no compilation errors either.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: You won't get an ORA-01403 from the cursor itself. If it doesn't find any rows it won't error, so the error is coming from the `select` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `count_var` may be too high, i.e. more than 120, because it doesn't have the same filters as the cursor. If you have any rows in `backup` where `column1` or `column2` are null, you'll fetch too many times, and the fetches when you run out data will return null; and your inner `select` will then try to match on null, which will get an ORA-01403.

You may also not have a matching record in `backup` where `column3 = var1`. It isn't clear you have consistent data.

But assuming that part is valid, you can loop over the cursor without a separate `count_var`:

```
open v_Cur for select column1, column2 from backup where ... ;
loop
  fetch v_Cur into var1,var2;
  exit when v_Cur%NOTFOUND;

  SELECT ID into variable3 from BACKUP where column3 = var1;
  UPDATE BACKUP SET column2 = var3;
end loop;
close v_cur;
```

The loop will exit when the fetch runs out of results from the cursor.

Not sure why you have so many arguments to the procedure. It looks like you only need `var3` to be passed in, and nothing really to be passed back out. `v_Cur` can just be declared as a `cursor` in the declare section, rather than as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

It's extremely difficult to try and put context behind the procedure without knowing what data you are passing, and what data is contained in the table.

The only other SQL that I would cause your NO_DATA_FOUND exception is:

```
"SELECT ID into variable3 from BACKUP where column3 = var1;"
```

Enclose this with a Begin Exception End Clause in your procedure and to try and Debug:

```
Begin
  SELECT ID into variable3 from BACKUP where column3 = var1;
Exception
When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: '||sqlerrm);
    Raise;  -- To ensure if this is the error, you will set get no_data_found raised... 
End;
```

Comment: The exception error stack will say which line is throwing the exception anyway. I don't see what adding another exception handler is really adding, other than losing that line number reference?

Comment: As I have suggested that you Raise, is so that you don't loose the line.  It gets added to the Error Stack.  But in any case, it's to prove the point, as to why the error is happening...

Comment: Thank you! I was actually analyzing the query with which I opened the cursor. This query actually was returning no data in some cases.